# Some hardware for multiple SIM cards SMS sending

Tags: gsm

I need some hardware for multiple SIM cards SMS sending. Preferably 200 sim cards. I would use Linux and some development boards like Raspberry pi etc. I have used raspberry with a USB dongle. Please advice solutions for multiple sim cards.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear to me. A SIM Card is a data storrage and cannot send SMS. What do you want to ask? How to clone one image onto 200 SIM cards?

Comment: "I need some hardware for multiple SIM cards SMS sending" I don't know what is unclear but imagine that instead of using 200 phones to hold IM cards I use a "hardware for that. I am aware that SIM does not send a ting. So I need a hard part.

Comment: Consider TWILIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a multiple of this [64 port bulk sms gsm modem with M35 module, 64 port gsm modem pool with IMEI change](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/64-port-bulk-sms-gsm-modem-with-M35-module-64-port-gsm-modem-pool-with-IMEI/32864716779.html) or go to AliBaba to request quotes for custom sms gsm modem. The Alibaba vendors list in [128 port multi sim bulk sms gsm modem](https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=128+port+multi+sim+bulk+sms+gsm+modem&viewtype=) may give you some ideas on how you can contact the seller to customize for your order.

I hope this helps.